# Characterization of stable theories

Tags: logic, model-theory

Let $\kappa$ be an infinite cardinal. A theory $T$ is called $\kappa$-stable if for all model $M\models T$ and all $A\subset M$ with $|A|\leq \kappa$ we have $|S_n^M(A)|\leq \kappa$.

A theory $T$ is called stable if it is $\kappa$-stable for some infinite cardinal $\kappa$.

**Question.** Is there any characterization for stable theories in terms of non-forking independence relation similar to Kim-Pillay  characterization for simple theories?

Comment: What is $S^M_n(A)$?

Comment: $S_n^M(A)=\{ p : p$ is a complete type over $ A \}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes. The easy way to see this uses the characterization of stable theories as those simple theories for which non-forking independence satisifies stationarity over models.

**Stationarity:** For any model $M$ and any set $B$, if $a$ is independent from $B$ over $M$, $a'$ is independent from $B$ over $M$, and $\text{tp}(a/M) = \text{tp}(a'/M)$, then $\text{tp}(a/MB) = \text{tp}(a'/MB)$.

In other words (together with the extension property), any type over $M$ has a unique independent extension to a type over $MB$.

So you can obviously characterize non-forking independence in stable theories by just taking the Kim-Pillay characterization of non-forking independence in simple theories and adding stationarity over models.

Actually, you can get away with fewer axioms than this; in particular, stationarity over models gives you the independence theorem over models for free. So there are various lists of axioms characterizing non-forking in stable theories:

- You can find a stable variant of the Kim-Pillay axioms in Casanovas's book *Simple Theories and Hyperimaginaries*, Definition 12.2 and Theorem 12.22.
- The fact that non-forking independence in stable theories can be axiomatically characterized may have first been noticed by Harnik and Harrington (long before Kim and Pillay started studying simple theories), see Axioms 0-3 and Theorem 5.8 in their paper *Fundamentals of Forking*.
- A more modern presentation of the Harnik and Harrington theorem is Theorem 8.5.10 in Tent and Ziegler's book *A Course in Model Theory*.

Comment: Thank you very much Alex. Is there any characterization for the other unstable classes for instance NSOP1, NTP1, NSOP3 and etc in terms of non-dividing independence? Also thanks for introducing http://www.forkinganddividing.com to me. It's a nice website.

Comment: @Lajos These questions are at the forefront of current research. Kaplan and Ramsey recently made a breakthrough by showing that NSOP1 can be characterized, not by non-forking or non-dividing independence, but by a generalization called Kim independence. See their paper here:  https://arxiv.org/abs/1702.03894 in particular Theorem 9.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your helpful comment.

Comment: Does the non-forking independence relation have a property that holds in strongly minimal theories but does not hold in stable theories?

Comment: @Lajos Well, in a strongly minimal theory, you can characterize forking in terms of algebraic dimension, and that characterization doesn't hold in an arbitrary stable theory. So in that sense yes. But to me that characterization has a different flavor than the usual kind of abstract properties like local character or stationarity.

Comment: Since we know that algebraic closure has a nice behavior in strongly minimal theories, can we use the following definition to characterize forking for every strongly minimal theory?  **A is nonforking independent from B over C iff the intersection of acl(AC) and acl(BC) is exactly equal acl(C).**

Comment: @Lajos No. The relation you wrote down does not characterize forking in algebraically closed fields, for example. The correct characterization is $\dim(a/BC) = \dim(a/C)$ for all finite tuples $a$ from $A$, where $\dim$ is the  dimension coming from the strongly minimal pregeometry (the maximum length of an algebraically indepedent subtuple).

Comment: Thank you Alex.

Comment: Let me to ask my question in other way. Can we characterize strongly minimal, omega stable, super stable, stable and simple theories just by non-forking independence relation?

Comment: @Lajos This comment thread is getting quite long. Maybe you should ask another question and include more motivation for what your goals are with these questions... But I'll say this: You already know characterizations of superstable, stable, supersimple, and simple theories in terms of properties of non-forking independence. I don't know a similar way of characterizing omega stable and strongly minimal theories purely in terms of forking, except by referring to other notions, like Morley rank (for omega stable) and acl dimension (for strongly minimal).

Comment: Thanks. Kim-Pillay characterization for simple theories is extremely amazing for me and I just was curious to know about a similar way of characterizing other theories.